# Transaction log partition still full after full backup?

Tags: exchange-2007, data-protector

I'm just curious and confused, how come after full backup of my Exchange Server 2007 SP1 with CCR using HP Data Protector (A06.11) one of my Storage Group transaction log partition still not cleared ?

While the other partitions can be as low as 0.1 GB after the full backup, but only this one particular stays about 11 GB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, are you using an Exchange aware backup application and is it set up correctly? Check you're specifically doing an Exchange aware backup job (as opposed to some shadow copy of the .edb and log files) and that all license keys and/or agents required are correctly installed and configured.

Secondly, assuming the application is doing an Exchange aware backup - are the backups actually completing successfully? Your backup application should be able to provide you with information as to whether the backup completed, failed or skipped some things - that would be a good log to interrogate. The Exchange server itself will also log events relating to ESE backups - they might be worth checking out in this case.

Lastly, it may sound like a dumb thing to say, but are the log files you see *definitely* associated with a database that you have just backed up? Is there any possibility these log files belong to another database that is either not being backed up, has backups failing, or the database itself has simply been deleted and the logs left in place.

Comment: yes, it works fine for all other database, but not this one only ? but however the mailbox is successfully backed up and no data is lost, just the transaction log is always not truncated ?

Comment: @Albert Widjaja - are these logs definitely associated with a mounted database? Are they increasing in size? Is the last modified date on the log files recent?

Comment: you are right Ben, I just found out that someone put the Windows backup directory in this log partition !!! ...facepalm... all is good now :-)